# Handling touches

Tags: objective-c, hittest, touches, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I have a UIView subclass with several subviews and I want to handle these events in the class:

- touchesBegan:withEvent:
- touchesMoved:withEvent:
- touchesEnded:withEvent:

but I also want these event to be called at the subviews. How can I accomplish that?

(I have already tried with hitTest, but I only get the touchesBegan event and no touches are send with the method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by overriding the following method at the main window:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent*)anEvent
```

I also check if it is the right event with through

```
if ([[[anEvent allTouches] anyObject] phase] == UITouchPhaseBegan)
```

I do the same for `UITouchPhaseMoved` and `UITouchPhaseEnded`, execute my custom code and then send `[super sendEvent:anEvent];`